# Qlikview - QVW execution failure

Tags: qlikview

We've got a QVW Script failing as it can't find the table to concatenate on, or load into the QVD.

ERROR messages shown on partial reload

**ERROR MESSAGE 1
Table not found
Concatenate (DATES) 
LOAD
'P' & Num(period,'00') & yearcode       AS #dFinYearPeriod,
Num(period,'00') as dFinYearPeriod,
Num(period,'00') as dFinPeriod,
'' as dMonthEnd,
Text(yearcode-1) & '/' & Text(yearcode-2000) AS dFinYear,
Num(yearcode) AS dFinYearOnly,
'' AS dMonth,
yearcode as dYear, 
'' AS dMonthNo,
'' as dFinYearEnd_Cur,
'' as dFinYearEnd_Prev**

**ERROR MESSAGE 2
Table not found
STORE DATES into C:\QlikView\QVD\DATES.qvd (qvd)**

We've been running back and forth through the script and can't find the cause of the error. Nothing has been changed in the QVW as far as we're aware, the OLEDB connection is fine, and the stored procedure involved is working correctly, as is the sql script.

from the error messages we're getting this looks to be the script failure point, but we can't work out why...

```
 DATES:

LOAD
'P' & Num(dFinPeriod,'00') & Date(dFinYearEnd_Cur,'YYYY')       AS     #dFinYearPeriod,
if(isnull(dMonthEnd),
Num(dFinPeriod,'00'),
        (if(dMonthEnd = '',
            Num(dFinPeriod,'00'),
                Num(dFinPeriod,'00') & ' (' & Text(Date    (dMonthEnd,'MMM')) & ')'
            )
        )
        )                   as dFinYearPeriod,
Num(dFinPeriod,'00') as dFinPeriod,
Date(dMonthEnd, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as dMonthEnd,
Text(Date(dFinYearEnd_Prev,'YYYY')) & '/' & Text(Date    (dFinYearEnd_Cur,'YY'))     AS     dFinYear,
Year(Date(dFinYearEnd_Cur, 'DD/MM/YYYY')) AS dFinYearOnly, //Return integer
Text(Date(dMonthEnd,'MMM')) AS dMonth,
Text(Date(dMonthEnd,'YYYY')) as dYear, 
Num(Month(dMonthEnd),'00') AS dMonthNo,
Date(dFinYearEnd_Cur,'DD/MM/YYYY') as dFinYearEnd_Cur,
Date(dFinYearEnd_Prev,'DD/MM/YYYY') as dFinYearEnd_Prev


//Filter to only financial year 2011/2 and later
 WHERE Text(Date(dFinYearEnd_Cur,'YYYY'))>=2012


;
SQL EXEC
dbo.spGetMonthEnds
;


//Add on the non-date f periods ie. 13 to 16
Concatenate (DATES) 
LOAD

'P' & Num(period,'00') & yearcode       AS #dFinYearPeriod,
Num(period,'00') as dFinYearPeriod,
Num(period,'00') as dFinPeriod,
'' as dMonthEnd,
Text(yearcode-1) & '/' & Text(yearcode-2000) AS dFinYear,
Num(yearcode) AS dFinYearOnly,
'' AS dMonth,
yearcode as dYear, 
'' AS dMonthNo,
'' as dFinYearEnd_Cur,
'' as dFinYearEnd_Prev
;
SQL Select

yearcode,
    period

   from

d_details 

   where 
    period <>'R' and
    period >12 and period <=16
    and yearcode >=2012
   group by
    yearcode, 
    period
   ;

    STORE DATES into $(vFolder)DATES.qvd (qvd);
    DROP Table DATES;
```

message on full reload

**Connecting to Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=WRVS;Data Source=rvs-psfsql-1-a;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=WRVS-CLICK-1-A;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False
Connected
DATES << EXEC
dbo.spGetMonthEnds
 48 lines fetched
DATES << Select
    yearcode,
    period
from
    d_details 
where 
 61 lines fetched**

the script execution seems to work ish, it's pulling lines back, but can't seem to find the DATES table to concatenate or store into the QVD.

The date manipulation taking place was all in place preiously, and there's nothing weird coming through on the SQL scripts to break any of that.

Any ideas please?

Thanks

Comment: not getting any error messages when running through the debugger either.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a Kerberos error unrelated to the Qlikview application itself

Error Code: 0x7  KDC_ERR_S_PRINCIPAL_UNKNOWN

I think it was related to some virus cleanup work that took place overnight. A server reboot solved the issue.